# Substring of char* to std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an array of `char`s and I need to extract subsets of this array and store them in `std::string`s.  I am trying to split the array into lines, based on finding the `\n` character.  What is the best way to approach this?

```
int size = 4096;
char* buffer = new char[size];
// ...Array gets filled
std::string line;
// Find the chars up to the next newline, and store them in "line"
ProcessLine(line);
```

Probably need some kind of interface like this:

`std::string line = GetSubstring(char* src, int begin, int end);`

Comment: @Jason: FYI [`while (stream.good())` and `while (stream.eof())` are usually wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Write `while (getline(...))` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd create the `std::string` as the first step, as splitting the result will be far easier.

```
int size = 4096;
char* buffer = new char[size];
// ... Array gets filled
// make sure it's null-terminated
std::string lines(buffer);

// Tokenize on '\n' and process individually
std::istringstream split(lines);
for (std::string line; std::getline(split, line, '\n'); ) {
   ProcessLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Might not be the quickest way, but this would be my first approach too.

Comment: It's the quickest to write. Probably not the quickest to run. Isn't that always the way? :)

Comment: i like your code `for (std::string line; std::getline(split, line, '\n'); ) `.

Comment: Nice. I think this is probably going to work for me. I'm going to mess around in a few hours when I get some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `std::string(const char *s, size_t n)` constructor to build a `std::string` from the substring of a C string. The pointer you pass in can be to the middle of the C string; it doesn't need to be to the very first character.

If you need more than that, please update your question to detail exactly where your stumbling block is.

Comment: Thanks, something like: `string(&buffer[10], 20)`? For some reason I got really poor performance when I tried this.

Comment: Well, your use case isn't clear. Are you doing this a million times a second? Twice? What? Define "poor performance."

Answer (score 1):

your best bet (best meaning easiest) is using [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) and convert the tokens to `std::string` via the constructor. (just note that pure `strtok` is not reentrant, for that you need to use the non standard `strtok_r`).

```
void ProcessTextBlock(char* str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    char* tok = strtok(str,"\n");
    while(tok != NULL)
    {
        ProcessLine(std::string(tok));
        tok = strtok(tok,"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first parameter of `strtok` is `char*`, not `const char*`.

Comment: @Steve: What consequence will that have on this answer?

Comment: strtok is an awful function as it mutates its input. There are much better ways in C++ to do this.

Comment: @Martin: my brain was in C mode when I wrote this, so just something quick and dirty (there was no requirement to preserve the string anyways). @Tomalak: I accidently made the param `const char*` out of sheer habit, then fixed it a minute later, so thats what Steve saw.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize you only wanted to process each line one at a time, but just in case you need all the lines at once, you can also do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;

char *s = buffer;
char *head = s;
while (*s) { 
  if (*s == '\n') { // Line break found
    *s = '\0'; // Change it to a null character
    lines.push_back(head); // Add this line to our vector
    head = ++s;
  } else s++; // 
}
lines.push_back(head); // Add the last line

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
for (it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); it++) {
  // You can process each line here if you want
  ProcessLine(*it);
}
// Or you can process all the lines in a separate function:
ProcessLines(lines);

// Cleanup
lines.erase(lines.begin(), lines.end());
```

I've modified the buffer in place, and the vector.push_back() method generates std::string objects from each of the resulting C substrings automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a substring of char* to std::string with a std::string's constructor:

```
template< class InputIterator >
basic_string( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Just do something like:

```
char *cstr = "abcd";
std::string str(cstr + 1, cstr + 3);
```

In that case str would be "bc".